# Passing event object along with param in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I want to be able to access the event object inside mapDispatchToProps along with sending in a param. How do you go about this?

This is what I have so far:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onRowClick: (id, event) => {
     console.log(id, event)
  },
})
```

In the view I have:

```
<TR key={`${index}`} onClick={() => onRowClick(id, event)}>
```

However, this is incorrect. How can you dispatch an event, pass along a param, and also have access to the event object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me tell you [why you shouldn't do it:](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling):

> The SyntheticEvent is pooled. This means that the SyntheticEvent
>   object will be reused and all properties will be nullified after the
>   event callback has been invoked. This is for performance reasons. As
>   such, you cannot access the event in an asynchronous way.

However, If you need to you can do it this way:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onRowClick: (id, event) => {
     console.log(id, event)
  },
})

<TR key={`${index}`} onClick={(event) => {
  event.persist(); // remove the synthetic event from the pool
  onRowClick(id, event);
}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `onClick={() => this.props.onRowClick(id, event)}`

What `mapDispatchToProps` does is, as its name suggest, map the dispatch function to the props

Read [this](https://medium.com/mofed/reduxs-mysterious-connect-function-526efe1122e4) for more on `connect` and `mapDispatchToProps`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass this event object from onClick handler to your onRowClick function. Like this:

```
onClick={event => this.props.onRowClick(id, event)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the event parameter in the arrow function:

`onClick={(event) => onRowClick(id, event)}>`

Also, you shouldn't be using arrow functions in render functions